# Slow distance calculation between several points

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, location, distance

i have some points that i want to get the distance from my phone current location to them, so far i have in my sql data base something like 12 locations and the google api does all of the calaulations with the app in like 2-3 seconds , the problem is that when the database will have 100 or 1000 locations it will take massive amount of time to calculate all of them and i cant go with that, how does apps calculate distancea to multiple restaurants or places so quickly?
I tried thinking of a way to do it without the google api but i don't really know one.
 is there a way to get distance between my location and a lot of different locations faster?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for road distance, or just distance between points. For  road distance, you probably can't do it without Google.

Comment: @cyanide  honestly i preffer road distance but if its impossible without google i would like to do it just distance between two points, the thing is that i probably need its longtitude and latitude but i have only the written adress of this points, how can i manage to calculate their distance?

Comment: Please add source code for distance calculation (probably 2-3 seconds is duration of current location determination, not distance calculation - formula for that not too complex).